# Mobile App that works on both Android and IOS for Barcode/Inventory Control

Tags: android, database, ios, mobile, inventory

I"m looking for a simple mobile app that can be used on both Android and iOS that does the following:

Imports an excel file with barcode details (barcode and description)
Scans a barcode
Looks up the barcode from the imported excel file, increments quani
Exports the results to an excel file
Emails the excel file

So far I have tried LoMag. I like the simplicity of it but it does not increment nor does it have a field for description.

The others I have looked at had too much bells and whistles.

Just need a simple one that does all of the above.

Comment: I cannot speak for the iOS part. But while waiting for a good answer, be welcome taking a look into my [Barcode section for Android](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_barcode). There are several for [inventory control](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_barcode_inventory), with some luck one of them matches and even has an iOS counter-part.